# What is the most efficient way to shift and add

Tags: assembly, x86-64, simd

I have a 64 bit memory  value  , the first 16 bits are an offset , what is the most efficient way to add the 16 bits to the other 48 bits.    The obvious logic is

```
ab = *ptr >> 48
result = *ptr & 0x0000 ffff ffff ffff + ab;
```

Also what would it be if it was 20/44 bits.

SIMD / Asm answers are good.

Im also ok storing the offset at the end , just for reference the main value will be the object address and the offset is the offset into the object .  Having the bits at the start allowes the collector to use a register to mask it but its better optomizing for the mutator.

Comment: Any half-decent compiler should already generate efficient code for this kind of expression, which doesn't leave much room for further optimisation.

Comment: That's a pretty strange way to encode a value, with the base in the lower 48 bits and the offset in the high 16 bits. But if that is indeed the structure, then the code you have written is the way to go. The only optimization I can see would be if you can dedicate a register to holding the value `0x0000ffffffffffff`, so your ASM could do the `and` instruction against the register rather than an immediate value. Of course, that would only help you if you were doing this very often, like in a loop.

Comment: Can you switch you format around? It's more convenient to have the offset in the lowest 16 bits. That way you can `movzx \ shr \ add`, which is afaik not directly better (though it shouldn't be worse), but has a smaller code size due to the elimination of that huge mask.

Comment: I smell microoptimization. Is this operation where the real performance bottleneck is? By the way, this is scalar operation that fits into 64 bit registers; SIMD is totally uncalled for.

Comment: Good questions - its not micro optomization , looking at using masked slices instead of interior pointers in a runtime.  Interior pointers have low size and performance but cause lots of issues  ( identifying the holding object for ref counting / mark ). Harold agree the above was so you can pack it fast but thats not as important.

Comment: Assuming this is a regular x86-64 48-bit logical address, using the low 16 is even better because you can use `sar` instead of `shr` in harold's method so that the address is automatically canonical (assuming the offset doesn't cause it to overflow into the gap).

Comment: I don't think there are any way to improve the performance much. Another way I can think of is `short *ofs = (short*)ptr + 3; result = *ptr & 0x0000 ffff ffff ffff + *ofs;`. But you should try several ways, benchmark and select the most appropriate for your own

Comment: ughoavgfhw , good tip on the canonical address..